# How to check if SSL bundle and domain certificates are made from existing private key

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

If I have pkey, csr (generated from pkey), bundle certificate and domain certificate files. How can I validate if both certificates are made for pkey?
Also is that the right way to validate ssl certificates. Any suggestions?
I would like to avoid using openssl cli tool and use php openssl library or any third party php library.

Comment: You probably could do it like shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php#111769), i.e. encrypt some data with the key from the cert and see if it can be decrypted successfully with your private key.

Comment: @HannoBinder will try it out.

Comment: [`openssl_pkey_get_public`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php) should be able to extract the public key from both your `pkey` and the certificate for you to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HannoBinder was close but it was a bit trickier. Apparently in PHP openssl one must get resource variables from certificate (tested also on certificate bundle file containing domain certificate for nginx) and private key file.

You can get certificate resource with `openssl_pkey_get_public`. But for private key you must get it with `openssl_pkey_get_private`. Its not to clearly written in documentation since probably these functions are quite universal.

Also i could not at first understand how to get public key from those resources. Apparently `openssl_pkey_get_details` can do that.

So in the end I resolved it this way.

```
$certPubKeyResource = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents($cert));
$publicKey1 = trim(openssl_pkey_get_details($certPubKeyResource)['key']);

$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents($pkey));
$publicKey2 = trim(openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key)['key']);

echo (!strcmp($publicKey1, $publicKey2) ? 'OK' : 'FAIL') . PHP_EOL;
```

I hope someone will have use for this since I could not find this particular case.

Also If someone will give more in depth answer with maybe some references to useful materials about SSL in PHP I could mark it as a correct answer instead of mine since im quite interested into getting full picture of this topic.